# GMP Library: undefined reference to mpz_prevprime

Tags: c, compiler-errors, gmp

I am facing an issue while using the gmp library:

```
> warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mpz_prevprime’; did you
> mean ‘mpz_nextprime’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
> 
> undefined reference to `mpz_prevprime' collect2: error: ld returned 1
> exit status
```

I've downloaded the gmp library (version 6.3.0) and installed it using MSYS this way (I've found the instructions in a tutorial):

```
cd gmp_folder
./configure
make
make check
make install
```

Then, I've included the library in my C file:

```
#include <gmp.h>
```

and also in my Makefile:

```
LDFLAGS = -lm -lgmp
```

What is strange is that the compiler seems to be able to find some functions but not this one. For example, the compiler does not complain if I change `mpz_prevprime` for `mpz_nextprime`.

Thank you for your help.

Appendix: perhaps the issue comes from my Makefile, see below:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g
LDFLAGS = -lm -lgmp
INCLUDES = -I./
SRCS = ./*.c
MAIN = cryptography.exe


all: $(MAIN)
    
$(MAIN): $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRCS) -o $(MAIN) $(LDFLAGS)


clean:
    rm ./cryptography.exe
```

My folder hierarchy:

*Main Folder*
|
|-------- C files (sources + headers) of my own
|-------- Makefile
|-------- *gmp subfolder*
              |
              |-------- gmp files

### EDIT & FIX:

the issue was GCC looking for another gmp library installed on my computer (I wasn't even aware of having it). I've specified the path on the correct gmp library (the one I've compiled):

In the Makefile, changing this line:

```
LDFLAGS = -lm -lgmp
```

for this one:

```
LDFLAGS = -lm -L./gmp_subfolder/.libs -lgmp
```

fixed my issue.

Comment: It is probably including an older gmp.h file from the standard include search path. Try adding `-I./gmp` (or wherever your gmp subfolder is).

Comment: @IanAbbott I've tried it but it didn't worked. However it gave me the idea to do the same for the gmp library: gcc was by default picking another one. I've put the fix in my post